# Shortening the formula

Tags: google-sheets

I can't figure out how to apply ranges for cells in formula, each time I try It doesn't work.

Google Sheet formula: `=IF(OR(B2=Items!$A$3;B2=Items!A$4;B2=Items!A$5;B2=Items!A$6;B2=Items!A$7;B2=Items!A$8;B2=Items!A$9;B2=Items!A$10;B2=Items!$A$11);"Melee";IF(OR(B2=Items!A$12;B2=Items!A$13;B2=Items!A$14;B2=Items!A$15;B2=Items!A$16);"Range";"Pick Your Weapon"))`

While in Excel this works:

```
=IF(OR(C1=A1:A3);"Melee";IF(OR(C1=A4:A6);"Range";"Unarmed"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF((B2:B=Items!A3)+(B2:B=Items!A4)+(B2:B=Items!A5)+(B2:B=Items!A6)+(B2:B=Items!A7)+(B2:B=Items!A8)+(B2:B=Items!A9)+(B2:B=Items!A10)+(B2:B=Items!A11); "Melee"; 
 IF((B2:B=Items!A12)+(B2:B=Items!A13)+(B2:B=Items!A14)+(B2:B=Items!A15)+(B2:B=Items!A16); "Range"; "Pick Your Weapon")))
```

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Items!A3:A11)); "Melee"; 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1; Items!A12:A16)); "Range"; "Pick Your Weapon")))
```